# The connection was reset in Upload Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, telerik

I code a example like telerik Upload demo but have the following error when submit(in FF):

**`The connection was reset.`**

The demo of telerik RadUpload is [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/manipulatingtheuploadedfiles/defaultcs.aspx?RadUrid=5c55f7df-39e7-4eaf-a6b8-07e3230c4cd5)

This is the code of .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage1.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="Main_Upload" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<title>Upload file</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="rsmScriptManager" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadProgressManager ID="rpmUploadFile" runat="server" />
<div style=" color:Green">Valid files(*.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.pdf)</div>
<telerik:RadUpload ID="rulFiles" runat="server" InitialFileInputsCount="2" MaxFileInputsCount="5" AllowedFileExtensions=".doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.pdf">
</telerik:RadUpload>
<telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" ID="rpaUpload"></telerik:RadProgressArea>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblNoResults" runat="server" Visible="True">No uploaded file!</asp:Label>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptValidResults" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FileName") %>(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ContentLength").ToString() + " bytes" %>)<br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<div style="color: red; padding-top: 40px;">Invalid files:</div>
<asp:Label id="lblNoInvalidResults" runat="server" Visible="True">No invalid files.</asp:Label>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInvalidResults" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        File: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FileName") %>(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ContentLength").ToString() + " bytes" %>)<br />
        Mime-type: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ContentType") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the code behind in *.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class Main_Upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindValidResult();
        BindInvalidResult();
    }

    private void BindValidResult()
    {
        if(rulFiles.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (UploadedFile validFile in rulFiles.UploadedFiles)
            {
                var targetFolder = Server.MapPath(Commons.PAGER.UPLOAD_FOLDER);
                validFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetFolder,validFile.GetName()),true);
            }

            lblNoResults.Visible = false;
            rptValidResults.Visible = true;
            rptValidResults.DataSource = rulFiles.UploadedFiles;
            rptValidResults.DataBind(); 
        }
        else
            {
            lblNoResults.Visible = true;
            rptValidResults.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void BindInvalidResult()
    {
        if(rulFiles.InvalidFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            lblNoInvalidResults.Visible = false;
            rptInvalidResults.Visible = true;
            rptInvalidResults.DataSource = rulFiles.InvalidFiles;
            rptInvalidResults.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblNoInvalidResults.Visible = true;
            rptInvalidResults.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and tell you with almost 100% certainty that the line that is causing this is:

```
var targetFolder = Server.MapPath(Commons.PAGER.UPLOAD_FOLDER);
```

It could be that you do not have permission to connect the server, or a variety of other issues.

To test this change "var targetFolder" to something like:

```
var targetFolder = @"C:\Users\j\Desktop\TEMP\"
```

Run this and it works perfectly, hence the idea that the path you're trying to access on the server is the problem.

Perhaps you should specify the path if possible. For example, if you are on a domain:

```
var targetFolder = @"\\server\Users\"
```

This would access that server and then the users folder therein that I have on my domain.